# News Feed via Graph API 'outdated'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-feed

On the Graph API documentation, the following is in brackets next to the News Feed endpoint:

> this is an outdated view, does not reflect the News Feed on facebook.com

This is a fairly critical method in any app using the Graph API, so what are we supposed to use? Is there a way to obtain a more accurate version of the News Feed with a different API?

I've noticed some differences between what is shown on the website and what is shown through the API but I assumed most of it was down to individual user permissions. Either way this issue is non-trivial and is starting to make regret choosing the Graph API over, say, FQL.

Comment: You can use FQL over the Graph API - where in the documentation is that line? The User documentation's description of the Home connection doesn't have that caveat: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#home

Comment: At http://graph.facebook.com scroll down to where it lists the main endpoints with links to each one. It says it in brackets next to "News Feed".

Comment: Ah, i see now, never noticed that note before :/

Comment: Still no answer to this? Crazy..

Answer (score 0):

You can use FQL to fetch the news feed. See the documentation under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/

But it seems that the results doesn't differ from the results via the graph api.